# Adding breaks in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have there be a line break between each item in my array. What my program does is create a new array using a few others which are based on the users answer to a question. I can't seem to figure out how to allow a line break between each item.

It's all done in JavaScript (with the exception of a little CSS but unimportant). I've tried using the < br > tag but it would just print the < br > instead.

I have four relevant arrays.
One for the questions:

```js
var questions = ["Do you like volunteering","Would you be interested in joining the musical/theatre?","Would you..."] //it goes on and on but I'll spare you
```

Another for all of the possible results:

```js
var clubs=[["All In","Interact Club","Key Club"," Environmental Club"],[" Fall Production"," Spring Musical"], "Student Government"," Tricorn"] //also goes on for a while
```

An empty array called recClubs which gets filled as they make choices.
And an empty array called choices for the choices themselves.

Then a little later I print the final outcome:

```js
function endQuizDiv(){
 //header of screen
 document.getElementById("question").innerHTML= "These are the clubs that you might be interested in";
 //prints the recommended clubs
 document.getElementById("recClubs").innerHTML= recClubs; 
}
```

And here is where recClubs gets its information:

```js
function eliminateClubs(){
 for(h=0;h<=personChoices.length;h++){
   if (personChoices[h]==1){
         recClubs.push(clubs[h]);
   }
 }
}
```

When recClubs is given to the user, all of the clubs are in one block of text and separated by commas. I want them to be separated by a line break. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could add the new line escape sequence each time you add items to the array

Answer (score 1):

You could use join for array  `recClubs.push(clubs[h].join(', <br/>'));` Actually you are adding array to innerHtml but it might be formatted string instead with `<br/>` tags

But data strucure should be :

```
var clubs=[["All In","Interact Club","Key Club"," Environmental Club"],[" Fall Production"," Spring Musical"], ["Student Government"],[" Tricorn"]].
```

or without changing data structure

```
function eliminateClubs(){
 for(h=0;h<=personChoices.length;h++){
   if (personChoices[h]==1){
     var addedValue = Array.isArray(clubs[h]) ? clubs[h].join(', <br/>') :clubs[h] + '<br/>';     
     recClubs.push(addedValue);
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited this comment because I was mistaken before:   I used this and it gave me this error: TypeError: clubs[h].join is not a function. I have multiple arrays inside of my array. When I only choose the response that gives one the arrays inside of the array, it does as I intend. Once I choose more than one response it displays the error.

Comment: It happens due to raw string  in your array   - you could wrap your string to array with single string value ("Student Government" becomes ["Student Government"]) or use Array.isArray(clubs[h]) before adding to recClubs variable.